# How does route-to work in the BSD pf firewall?

Tags: routing, firewall, openbsd, bsd, pf

I've recently learned about the `route-to` functionality in the pf firewall, and I wonder how it works. Is it similar to the "policy-based routing" system in linux? How does `route-to` allow the overriding of the system routing table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pf's `route-to` allows to *define* policy-based routing (PBR) *using the same firewall's ruleset*. The PBR itself is then being done at kernel-level during traffic processing according to firewall ruleset shipped onto kernel level by `pf`'s user-space utility `pfctl`.

In Linux, Netfilter (which many people erroneously call `iptables` by its main control utility's name) stays away from PBR functionality except that it still can be used to change/assign "marks"<sup>1</sup> that PBR's rules<sup>2</sup> might make use of in addition to other "selectors".

__

1. `man iptables-extensions`'s excerpt:

> MARK — This target is used to set the Netfilter mark value associated with the packet. *It can, for example, be used in conjunction with routing based  on  fwmark* (needs  *iproute2*).  If  you  plan  on doing so, note that *the mark needs to be set in the PREROUTING chain of the mangle table to affect routing*.  The mark field is 32 bits wide.

2. user space utility `ip` (of that "iproute2") is typically used for that: `ip rule …`

Comment: Great answer me bruh!